# Is it possible to store in a container a member overload?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, overloading

My question is simple, yet the solution is not obvious to me.

I want to get an overload set (macros allowed in case I need) into a container. The overloaded functions are member functions. I want something like this:

```
std::function<void (MyClass &, std::string const &)> myFuncs = 
{&MyClass::f1, &MyClass::f2};
```

I tried several things I will not post the code for right now, but basically, I want that to work even if I need an overload for lifting the overload set into a functor. I know how to do that with free functions but I am failing to do it for member functions. Any idea if this is possible in a generic way?

Comment: Why don't you just make a vector of non-static class function pointers?

Comment: I am not sure I get you. What do you propose @VTT

Comment: I suggest to use a container such as `::std::vector` and to store pointers to overloaded member functions there.

Comment: *I will not post the code for right now* Well, it would help if you do. Without an example, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I had thought at first:

I can do the following:

```
//Choose overload
using MyFType = void (MyClass::*)(std::string const &);


static const MyFType funcs[] = {&MyClass::f1, &MyClass::f2};
```

That will convert to the correct overload given by the left hand side of the definition.